# How to retrieve the id of the received local notification in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app that includes scheduled notifications that are uniquely identified by the Notification_ID. The response to each notification is different, but I don't to create multiple Channel_ID (same channel_ID for all notifications). When I receive a notification, how can I retrieve the Notification_ID?

Let's say I triggered 3 notifications with different Ids: (same channel ID)

1- notificationManager.notify ("100", builder.build()); //first notification with ID 100

2- notificationManager.notify ("200", builder.build()); //second notification with ID 200

3- notificationManager.notify ("300", builder.build()); //third notification with ID 300

When I receive all 3 notifications and press on one of them, how can I retrieve the ID of that notification?

If anyone can help, it would be great.

Comment: How you are specifying different ids to each notification? is it randomly generated or comes from some source?

Comment: No it is not random. Generated by specific date and time selection, and this ID is stored internally. When I receive the notification, I would like to access the ID in order to retrieve the specific data stored.